# Get the length of the input that has the same value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the total count of the email inputs with the specific value, by jQuery.

I tried to use `[value=somevalue]` selector, as shown in the following code:

```js
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('#counter').text( $('input[value="test"]').length);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="email" value="test">
<input type="email">
<input type="email">
<button>test</button>
<br><br><span style="color:red;">Length: </span>
<span id="counter"></span>
```

But it only shows 1 no matter what value user types there.

Even if user removes `test` value from the first input element, to click the button, it still says 1.

Any idea, help please?

Comment: Are you trying to count the characters? Or you are counting how many email address?

Comment: It is not clear what is your intention. Do you want to check number of inputs in which user has typed something (can be anything, dynamic value, as you said)? Empty inputs shouldn't be counted, in that case...

Comment: Ah, if inputs have same value, type number of inputs, right?

Comment: @sinisake if user input 'test' to all input fields then user clicked the button, length should return 3 since all the 3 fields have a value of test, the problem in my code is, it seems the dynamic value that the user put in does not recognized not unless if you set a default value then the scripts will read it.

Comment: Yes, i understand, you need to re-check values on button click, and to compare it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think following is what you want:

```js
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    var modelv = 'test';
    var matches = $('input').filter(function() { return $(this).val() === modelv; });
    $('#counter').text( matches.length );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="email" value="test">
<input type="email">
<input type="email">
<button>test</button>
<br><br><span style="color:red;">Length: </span>
<span id="counter"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to compare dynamic values (as user typed), you can do something like this: loop through each email input, place values in array, check if there are duplicates, and count it. (There are countless methods to find dupes in array, but i've used simple counter variable, and checked if value already exists in array).

```
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    vals = [];
    count = 0;
    flag = false;
    $('input[type="email"]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        v = $(this).val();
        if (vals.includes(v)) {
          flag = true;
          count++;
        }
        vals.push(v);
      }
    });
    console.log(vals);
    if (flag) {
      $('#counter').text(count + 1);
    } else $('#counter').text(count)
  });
});
```

Demo:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    vals = [];
    count = 0;
    flag = false;
    $('input[type="email"]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        v = $(this).val();
        if (vals.includes(v)) {
          flag = true;
          count++;
        }
        vals.push(v);
      }
    });
    console.log(vals);
    if (flag) {
      $('#counter').text(count + 1);
    } else $('#counter').text(count)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="email">
<input type="email">
<input type="email">
<button>test</button>
<br><br><span style="color:red;">Length: </span>
<span id="counter"></span>
```